# Seeing errors only after ng build

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

In an Angular/CLI/TypeScript 2.3 app, I have a code which spits out errors of type:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'myValue' of object '#'

And it is most probably an attempt to mutate a property of an object declared with a `const`. The cause of the problem is not my point here.

My point and question is that I see them only after `ng build` but not when run locally. How can I make them visible during `ng serve`?

**Edit**

It looks as if the `'use scrict'` was injected into the built code but not the one run by Webpack during `ng serve`.

Quoting this [blog post comment](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const)

```
const foo = 27;
// Any of the following uncommented lines throws an exception.
// Assignment operators:
foo = 42;
```

but this will:

```
'use strict'; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<---------------------!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
const foo = 27;
// Any of the following uncommented lines throws an exception.
// Assignment operators:
foo = 42;
```

Comment: `ng serve` builds the app and also starts a web server. So whatever error you're getting on `ng build` you should see on `ng serve`.

Comment: That's what I thought. But apparently it is not the case.

Comment: What command exactly are you running? `ng build --prod`?

Comment: Yes, for building the deploy site. For local dev ng serve with --port and --host flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using `ng build --prod` as mentioned in the comments by [@developer033](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4911842/developer033).

Production (AoT) compilation and non-production compilation are two different things. Prod flag is more "strict".

You can take a look at at do's/don'ts of production code from this link: https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox

And to simply answer your question on how to detect the errors from `ng build --prod` with `ng serve`: you can't. Maybe if you setup your linters with AoT settings, your IDE can tell you what and what not to do.

Comment: So, if I run `ng serve --aot` isn't it going to be a good preflight test? (Thanks for the sandbox link -  a really useful resource)

Comment: @user776686 yes but `ng serve --aot` and `ng build --aot` take same time to boot the app. What I mean is `ng serve` and `ng serve --aot` are different things. And in order to make sure your app runs correctly in aot mode you need to use the `--aot` option.

Comment: Yes, my point was to be able to see errors *before* I deploy to a server.

Comment: @user776686 that's what I'm saying, you can't unless you use the `--aot` flag before you deploy it to the server. And as I've mentioned the only thing that comes to mind is that generating your custom rules efor typescript lints so that when you make a mistake in your code your IDE will warn you.

Comment: What about Ivy in Angular 9+? It is not using JIT in development, or is it?
But I still have this issue of many errors going unnoticed until production build